# Using NSDateComponents to test date equality when times differ

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, equality, nsdatecomponents

I want to test if two `NSDate` objects have the same year/month/day but different times of day.  Here is my code:

```
NSDate *date1 = [dataDictionary1 valueForKey:@"date"];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];
NSDate *newDate1 = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSDate *date2 = [dataDictionary2 valueForKey:@"date"];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date2];
NSDate *newDate2 = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

However, `newDate1` is returning with `2012-05-01 05:00:00 +0000` and `newDate2` with `2012-05-01 04:00:00 +0000`.

The hours are not zero because my time zone is not GMT, but why are the two hours not equal?  Do you know a better way to test if dates with differing times are equal? (That is, more efficient than getting date components for each and testing equality for each day/month/year?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDate *date1 = [dataDictionary1 valueForKey:@"date"];
long noTime1 = [date1 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] / (60*60*24);

NSDate *date2 = [dataDictionary2 valueForKey:@"date"];
long noTime2 = [date2 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] / (60*60*24);

if (noTime1 == noTime2) {
    // same date
}
```

Of course this only works if you simply want to compare the date portion and don't care about the actual day, month, or year values.

Comment: Thanks, rmaddy.  That's really clean.  In this particular instance, I do need the day info, but there are other spots in this same project where your answer is going to be very useful :)